# Javascript String.replace global match with substring

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, gruntjs

I am using Grunt with [`grunt-string-replace`](https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace) in order to substitute all the occurrences of my development environment URL to my production ones during deploy. I have my `devRoot` and `stageRoot` saved as variables, and I want to use them to apply the substitution.

I tried two different approaches:

1. Using RegExp as the pattern works perfectly, except that I cannot use string interpolation inside the RegExp, so I cannot dynamically add my `devRoot` to the pattern. So I tried assigning the RegExp directly to the object property, or even assigning a function which returned the RegExp, but that didn't work at all.
2. Since my substitution is fairly easy, I quit the first approach and just decided to use the replacement with a string, like so:

   ```
   'string-replace': {
        rootUrl: {
             options: {
                 replacements: [{
                     pattern: '<%= devRoot %>',
                     replacement: '<%= stageRoot %>'
                 }]
             }
         }
   }
   ```

This works but **replaces just the first occurrence of my pattern**. So my question is: **is there a way to do a global *case insensitive* replacement with a substring?** Similar to what the RegExp `gi` options do.

Alternatively: **how would I pass the interpolated RegExp to this object property**?

Answer (score 1):

If by interpolated you mean concatenate the variables value into the regular expression, then you can do it using RegEx's constructor syntax. i.e. these two are equivalent:

```
/abc/gi
```

and

```
new RegExp('abc', 'gi');
```

but since the second one receives a string you can concatenate it with a var, like you would a normal string (after all it is a normal string):

```
new RegExp('abc' + devRoot, 'gi');
```

Comment: I tried this as per (1.) but for some reason the resulting RegExp is not parsed correctly by the Grunt Task.

Comment: what do you mean with 'as per (1.)'? Frankly I don't know much about grunt, and am trying to illustrate the different ways you have in JavaScript for instantiating a regular expression, in the hopes you didn't know about the second form and can try it out in your grunt script and work from there. In any case, if it still doesn't work, post the exact code you're using and I'll try to help as best I can (after all, grunt seems quite interesting, and I'd love an excuse to read up on it before going to bed :P)

Comment: *as per (1.)* I meant as I described in point number 1 in my question. My exact code is this: `pattern: new RegExp('<%= devRoot %>', 'gi')` (the rest is the same as the one posted in the question). I have to use the ERB template style to access the variable, if I don't Grunt complains it's undefined (probably some scoping problems). And yes, Grunt is a lifechanger. I have started since a month ago and am not going back :)

Comment: so the regexp gets created as `/<%= devRoot %>/gi`? when you tried using a property, what syntax did you use?

Comment: This is the syntax I used in (1.). I also tried `pattern: function(){ return new RegExp('<%= devRoot %>', 'gi') }`

Comment: what if you try `pattern: (function(){ return new RegExp('<%= devRoot %>', 'gi') } ())`?

Comment: Nope… nothing. Also it is very difficult because I have no clue on how to successfully debug Grunt.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it may be of any help but I am able to replace all the instances of the word using the Reg Exp Pattern without using the function. I just use the /<%= devRoot %>/ig and it work great!